# Using .htcaccess to redirect to www. AND add trailing forward slash

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have searched around for a while and had a go at tweaking this file myself and I'm almost there but there is one case which I can't figure out...
How to get both a www. AND a forward slash at the same time

If I type in [spectrl.com](http://spectrl.com), it redirects to www.spectrl.com CORRECT - Adds www.

If I type in [www.spectrl.com/ebaycalculator](http://www.spectrl.com/ebaycalculator) it redirects to www.spectrl.com/ebaycalculator/ CORRECT - Adds /

But if I type in spectrl.com/ebaycalculator I get a 404 error when it should go to www.spectrl.com/ebaycalculator/

Here's my .htcaccess file, kept at the root:

```
RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://spectrl.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing and re-uploading .htaccess and then clearing the cache, everything seems to be working as intended using my original code in the question.

Hope this will be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

@Kavi

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "^(?:www\.)?(.*)"    [NC]
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!/$"
RewriteRule "(.*)"           "http://www.%1%/$1/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^www\."            [NC]
RewriteRule "(.*)"           "http://www.%1/$1"   [R=301,L]
```

The first `RewriteCond` captures the hostname (without any leading `www.`) in the reference `%1`.  That condition will always succeed.

The second `RewriteCond` checks for the trailing slash; if not found, the next `RewriteRule` will be triggered.

That first `RewriteRule` uses the captured `www.`-less host name to construct a redirect that includes `www.` and the training `/`.

The second stanza will be triggered if the request falls through because it *does* have a trailing `/`.  It checks for a leading `www.`, and does the same sort of redirect (only without appending a slash, since there's already one there) as the first stanza.

At least, that's how is *should* work; I haven't tested it. :-)

Comment: I'm afraid that's not working.
The trailing slash gets added but the www. part is broken, it redirects to www./

Comment: I reverted to my original and now that's doing the same! Very strange behaviour...